# Excel 2013 workbooks in separate instances of Excel communicating via linkage

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 Excel workbooks with a lot of event based VBA code.  If they run under the same instance of Excel (2003 or 2013) eventually, the events trigger at the same time and cause a crash.

So, in Excel 2003, I open the workbooks (A and B) in separate instance of excel, and workbook A has a link to "pull in" live updating date from workbook B using the format

```
{=Excel.Sheet.8|'\\server\B.xls'!'!Sheet1!R1C1:R300C8'}
```

I first open "B" in its own instance,and then i open "A" also in its own instance.  "A" asks if I want to Update Links from external workbooks, and I choose "Update"

In Excel 2003, this works perfectly. The workbooks run under separate instances of Excel, and therefore share no memory footprint, and everything is safe and stable, but A gets a live streaming update from B (not from the saved file, but from the live running instance).  So, even tho they are running in separate instances of Excel 2003 in memory, they are able to communicate via the linkage.

In excel 2013, the default behavior is to open all workbooks in the same instance of excel (even if you try to open the Excel.exe as in 2003 before opening the next workbook).  I'm aware that I can force Excel 2013 to open a new instance of Excel via the Ctrl + right-click menu option, however those instances of Excel are now UNABLE to communicate with each other as they did in 2003.

In excel 2013, when I create the same linkage between A and B, the only data that A can pull from B is whatever has been saved down to to the file server. "A" has no "hooks" into the "live" instance of "B".

This is a change from Excel 2003.  In 2003, if "B" is opened first, and then "A" is opened, then "A" recognized that "B" is open and will hook to the live running instance of "B" (even though they do not run in the same instance).

Is there any way for excel 2013 workbooks to both run in separate instances (for stability), but have those instances "hook" the live processes...which is what was capable in Excel 2003?

Comment: I only have one event driven routine so excel has never crashed for me using the same instance. Have you tried setting enableevents=false just before the event occurs?

Comment: doesn't solve my issue...and for a variety of reasons, i'm looking to get back functionality that i previously had with Excel 2003...but is now no longer available.   wtf microsoft...

Comment: Clearly msft wants you to downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Within one of the workbooks (the first one you choose to pull up), you could define 2 instances of Excel using VBA. You can then refer to each instance and use Application.Run to execute subroutines within each Excel program.

As an example...

```
    Sub FromBook1()

Dim EApp1 as Excel.Application
Dim EApp2 as Excel.Application
Dim Bk1 as Excel.Workbook
Dim Bk2 as Excel.Workbook

'Set the first object to this instance of Excel (the first book you opened)
Set EApp1 = GetObject(,"Excel.Application")
Set EApp2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set Bk1 = EApp1.Workbooks("[name of workbook #1]")
Set Bk2 = EApp2.Workbooks.Open("[path for workbook #2]")

'Put your condition/event in here (e.g., an if/then)

'If the condition is triggered
With EApp2
  .Run("[Name of subroutine in book 2 to call]")
End With

    End Sub
```